# What is the efficient way/environmental requirements to stream a 1080p file via Hotspot in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc, wifi-hotspot

I'm trying to stream a Divx 1080p 25fps file from a Ubuntu 16 to another Ubuntu 16 PC via Hotspot using VLC.

**PC#1** use VLC as streamer and PC#2 uses VLC client.

Tenda w311mi is connected to PC#1 and it is made as hotspot (Hotspot setup is done through Ubuntu Network Manager).

**PC#2** uses the same tenda w311mi to connect to this hotspot.

Now when I try to this Divx 1080p file, the video streaming is not efficient and the video is very scrambled or disturbed.

Can anyone help in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way to accomplish this is by using one of the many GitHub PHP pseudo streaming projects.

This approach is dirt simple + provides true streaming + can be setup/working in a few minutes.

[site:github.com pseudo streaming php 206](https://www.google.com/search?ei=zUsEWr_dJ8rbjwS7z7vIAQ&q=site%3Agithub.com%20pseudo%20streaming%20php%20206&oq=site%3Agithub.com%20pseudo%20streaming%20php%20206&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3188.5505.0.5616.8.8.0.0.0.0.144.793.5j3.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.H2rVb0lde6o) turns up 1250 such projects.

[Pseudo Streaming MP4’s with PHP](https://gist.github.com/BackFront/3908f6a4810b4440d05daf7b100cd7a8) is a great starting point. Just put in a path to your video + your done. If you have many videos, modify this code to take ?video=path arg or use one of the other multi-video projects.

I've used ffmpeg + VLC + various Apache mod_* approaches.

PHP pseudo streaming will have you up + running way faster than any other approach.